# Observing Room table with without LifecycleOwner reference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, coroutine

I have a component in my app that performs specific work when the database gets updated. In order to observe Room table, I need to use LiveData which requires me to pass LifecycleOwner. My component has nothing to do with any of the views so I don't have a Lifecycle. How can I observe on Room table without a reference to LifecycleOwner? I am using Kotlin and Coroutines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `LiveData.observeForever(Observer)`. Do not forget to call `LiveData.removeObserver(Observer)` once you do not want to get updates anymore, as using this method you register an observer that will receive updates forever (as the method's name suggests). [(Docs source)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html#observeForever(android.arch.lifecycle.Observer%3CT%3E))